# npm install bcrypt with node 5.0.0 and npm 3.5.1

Tags: node.js, npm, bcrypt

```
I update node and npm and now when I want to install bcrypt it return this error:
```

> sudo npm install bcrypt --save
>
> ```
> > bcrypt@0.8.5 install /Users/XXX/node_modules/bcrypt
> > node-gyp rebuild
>
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
>   SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bcrypt_lib.node
> ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> make: *** [Release/bcrypt_lib.node] Error 1
> gyp ERR! build error 
> gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
> gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
> gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
> gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.5.0
> gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
> ```
>
> "rebuild"
>       gyp ERR! cwd /Users/XXX/node_modules/bcrypt
>       gyp ERR! node -v v5.0.0
>       gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.0
>       gyp ERR! not ok 
>       npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
>       npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "bcrypt" "--save"
>       npm ERR! node v5.0.0
>       npm ERR! npm  v3.5.1
>       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> ```
> npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.5 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
> npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
> npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
> npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
> npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
> npm ERR!     npm bugs bcrypt
> npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
> npm ERR!     /Users/XXX/npm-debug.log
> ```

Comment: Could you please specify a question?

Comment: I solved it. I forgot to update xcode.

Comment: In that case, would you mind answering your own question explaining how you solved it and mark it as the correct answer, to make it easier in the future for users experiencing the same issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. I forgot to update xcode. App Store -> Find xcode -> Update (1 hour more or less to updated with my connection ADSL 10MB) and then run sudo xcode-select -s /path/to/xcode/Contents/Developer.

You need also new command line tool and node-gyp.

Comment: I'd like to add here: if it's still failing, make sure the project your using doesn't have a `package.json` file mandating an incompatible version of `bcrypt` with your environment. It should actually match the numbers here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt [Using `~0.8.0` as my version number (node v5.0.0 is current at present) instead of the wrongly mandated `^0.7.0` in the project I downloaded, fixed the issue for me].